# RestClient not reaching its own endpoints during SpringBoot Application test

Tags: java, spring-boot, testcontainers

## Domain

This is a question regarding the **RestClient** introduced in Spring Framework 6.1 M2 (Jul, 2023) that supersedes RestTemplate.

## Setup

- SpringBoot v3.2.0 (Nov, 2023)
- Testcontainers v1.19.3

## Scenario

I already use the well known TestRestTemplate - works fine.
But because I am curious, I like to step up to the next level.

- Why mocking (use the TestRestTemplate), if I can use the 'real endpoint'?

In other words: I want to send a 'real' request using the recently established Spring Framework's **RestClient**.

Explicitly:

- The application sends requests in its tests to its own exposed endpoints.

### Hands on

Therefore I set up the Java microservice with testcontainers.
Additionally the application context is loaded completely (is this correct?).

```
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        properties = "spring.profiles.active=integrationtest"
)
@Testcontainers
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {EndpointApplicationTest.Initializer.class})
class EndpointApplicationTest {
       ... .. . CODE . .. ...
}
```

At this point I expect the application to expose its ports and mappings.

### Problem

Although the **RestClient** works well for any external resource, it does not reach its own mappings:

```java
        String url = "http://localhost:PORT/actuator";

        String givenAnswer = restClient.get()
                .uri(url)
                .retrieve()
                .body(String.class);
```

The upper code snippet fails with:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:PORT/actuator": null
```

The service is still pretty plain and no further security (e.g. for https) is set.

### Additional actuator behaviour

Running the application manually (no test run, no testcontainers), the actuator is available as expected e.g. via browser (`http://localhost:PORT/actuator`).

### Residue questions

1. Is SpringBoot not exposing its ports during test?
2. Do I miss something else?

Comment: Have you tried  to use  `@LocalServerPort` yet ? If I understand your question in the right way.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting - I will try it next days   ;-)

Comment: let me know if it help you.

Comment: It works   :D ...
I will add the answer shortly   ;-)

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

`@LocalServerPort` -> helped me out

## Reasoning

Although the Testcontainer with the application opens its connection at port e.g. 8081 this is not seen by the SpringBoot application.
Moreover, the missmatch is irritating, because the app is supposed to open inside the container at 8081 (referring to configuration in `application.yml`).
Still, the winning configuration **during the test** is `SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT`.

Hence, with each run the localServerPort changes somewhere in the upper range (30000 < x < 65535)

## Sample Code

```java
class EndpointApplicationTest {

    private static final Logger logger =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEndpointApplicationTest.class);
    public static DockerComposeContainer<?> dcEnv;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;
    private final RestClient restClient = RestClient.create();


    @Test
    @DisplayName("Sample-Rest request")
    public void RequestTest() {

        // URLS
        String uriBase = String.format("http://localhost:%s/v1", port);
        logger.info(String.format("Port: %s for URL-Base: %s", port, uriBase));

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");

        Map<String, String> applicationJSON = new HashMap<>();
        applicationJSON.put("foo", "bar");

        // Rest call
        String response = restClient.post()
                .uri(uriBase + "/route")
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(applicationJSON)
                .retrieve()
                .body(String.class);
        assertEquals("Processed successfully", response);
    }
```

## Benefits

1. The test are more equal to the running environment, as no `faked RestTemplate`is needed.
2. The `java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode` is not thrown (compared to the RestTemplate) .. (Note: my personal side-effect).
3. It can be decided, if a **ResponseEntity** OR an **unwrapped class** shall be returned.

```java
            // Rest call
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restClient.post()                    
                    . .. ... .. .
                    .toEntity(String.class);
```